# Calculating Time Difference in military time for C++

Tags: c++

I have to write a program that gives the difference between two times that are given in military time format. For example,

Please enter the first time: 1730
Please enter the second time: 0900
Output = 15 hours 30 minutes

Here is the program I came up with (*Not allowed to use if statements, loops or functions)

I just need to know whether this is correct or incorrect?

```
int main()
{

    int first;
    int second;

    cout << "Please enter the first time:";
    cin >> first;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Please enter the second time:";
    cin >> second;
    cout << endl;

    int am = first - 1200;
    second = second + 1200;

    int amhour = am/100;
    int ammins = am%100;

    int hours = second - amhour*100;

    int real_hr = hours - 40;
    int final_time = real_hr - ammins;
    int final_hours = final_time/100;
    int final_mins = final_time%100;

    cout << final_hours << " hours and " << final_mins << " minutes." << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does it give you the correct output for all of the input you've tried? Surely you can decide if it's correct or not like that. 2200, 2117 doesn't give a proper result, so your answer is no the program is not correct.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14667076/c-time-difference-in-military-time

Comment: I don't understand the use of the `- 40` or the purpose of converting to a less mathematically manageable time system like `am/pm`.

Comment: Hint: Time expressed as `HHMM` for 24-hour clocks is actually `HH*60 + MM` minutes into the day (ignoring Daylight Saving Time). Convert to minutes, do the math, convert back to hours/minutes. Done. I also *loathe* questions like this because they're wrong. There is no way to know how many minutes and hours have elapsed between `0030` and `0400` without knowing what day it is and what time zone you're talking about unless it's explicitly talking about [Zulu Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).

Comment: Whay would anyone use 12-hour am/pm clock anyways? It makes as much sense as, dunno, measuring distance in miles... ;)

Comment: BTW, is second time always later? Because 9:00 - 17:30 may be 8h 30 min as well.

Comment: Yes the second time must always come later. Basically 1730 is actaully      5: 30 am and 0900 is 9 pm. In that case the difference is  15 hours and 30 minutes.

Comment: It's the other way round - 17:30 is 5:30 pm.

Answer (score 0):

I would first convert each time into "minutes since midnight", then subtract the first from the second, then use that to form your output.

However, you may need to take into account that the subtraction may give you a *negative* number if, for example, the first time is `2330` and the second is `0030` (crossing the day boundary).

You can fix that by simply adding 1440 minutes (one day) to the difference and then using the modulo operator to reduce that if it's more than a day.

So I would start with something like:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    // Get times from user.

    int first, second;
    std::cout << "Please enter the first time:  "; std::cin >> first;
    std::cout << "Please enter the second time: "; std::cin >> second;

    // Convert both to minutes since midnight.

    first = (first / 100) * 60 + first % 100;
    second = (second / 100) * 60 + second % 100;

    // Work out time difference in minutes, taking into
    // account possibility that second time may be earlier.
    // In that case, it's treated as the following day.

    const int MINS_PER_DAY = 1440;
    int minutes = (second + MINS_PER_DAY - first) % MINS_PER_DAY;

    // Turn minutes into hours and residual minutes, then output.

    int hours = minutes / 60;
    minutes = minutes % 60;
    std::cout << hours << " hours and " << minutes << " minutes.\n";
}
```